# How To Conditionally Include A Short Code Depending On The HTTP_REFERER

Tags: shortcode, conditional-tags, conditional-content

I want to show a form at the end of my purchase-confirmation page only in the case where the previous page / HTTP_REFERER is the checkout page. I've tried lots of different ideas.

For example, I was hoping the PHP Snippets would solve my problem. But it doesn't appear to work at all with the newest version of Wordpress.

Anyway, I need something like this:

```
Thank you for your purchase! [edd_receipt]

    [insert_php]if( strpos($_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER], "checkout" ) == true ):[/insert_php] 
        [wpforms id="123"]
    [insert_php] endif; [/insert_php]
```

Ideas?

Comment: Note that shortcodes that let you put PHP code inside posts or content boxes are incredibly dangerous, and a massive security problem. You also loose access to all the WP APIs and any request data. You should uninstall the plugin for that ASAP. Also note that the referrer can be spoofed and isn't secure. Have you contacted EDD support? This question requires EDD specific knowledge, WP general expertise will have limited value here, you should go to the EDD communities and their developer support and docs

Comment: How is asking about shortcodes not specific to WP? I was just about to give a answer, thanks a lot. I really hate this trigger happy mods on SO sites.

Comment: Abuse of power obviously. This because his personal opinion is that he should not use that plugin for security reasons he just declares a WP specific question as not WP specific.

Comment: @RradRhoads You can write use the `echo do_shortcode('[any_shortcode]');` in actual php code to conditionally call it. And if you want to get rid of that plugin you could write you own shortcode that calls another shortcode on condition.

Comment: @RradRhoads You missed the quotes on `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` and your string check is flawed. Should be `if ( false !== strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'checkout' ) ) {`

Comment: @TomJNowell This is not an EDD specific question. That happens to be my particular context. But the question could be generalized to just ask how to conditionally include/exclude a shortcode. Please reopen the question.

Comment: Your approach is wrong. Shortcodes are not a programming language but a an html macro. If you need the macro to be "smarter" you should modify the shortcode code and not the content

Comment: As for arguing.... this is usually pointless and annoying to do in the comments or question body. If you wish to discuss whatever issue you have with moderation here, you are invited to the "the loop" chat or raise it as a question on the meta site

Comment: Bringing up EDD is just a excuse to close this, could be anything. Its a generic question how to do this. I thought this sites are about answering question and not lecture and rant about how to do it "better". I actually have seen people reminded of this on other SO sites. But @BradRhoads I basically already told you how to do this. You just do one a single [insert_php] block and in that block you call the shortcode with php based on whatever condition you desire. I can also can post a simple plugin that creates a shortcode that calls another shortcode when a condition is met if reopened.

Comment: upvoted and voted to reopen as this is clearly not EDD specific, needs more reopen votes though. :-)

Comment: but whatevs, add to your child theme functions.php: `add_shortcode('checkout-referer', 'check_checkout_referer'); function check_checkout_referer($atts, $content) {if (strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"], "checkout" ) == true) {return do_shortcode($content);} }` then wrap like [checkout-referer][wpforms id="123"][/checkout-referer]

Comment: To do this properly will require modification of the checkout page so that it bundles a value you can check for. Referrers are not reliable or secure, and a lot of browsers and extensions strip the referrer out